# How to get the the required data from a string using Regexp or any string manipulation method

Tags: python, regex, string, instagram-api

I have many Json responses from an instagram API which contains data like this:-

```
"bio": "5-yr online store  Real pictures Mirror Quality 1:1 Whatsapp/Viber +861776345378 spikydudewonderland@gmail.com ✈️✈️Worldwide Shipping",
```

More Examples:-

```
"bio": "Девочки это наша новая страничка.Только копии Lux, искателям дешевых подделок не беспокоить. По всем вопросам viber,whatsapp +79128743333 Лианна"
"bio": "Recruitment AgentsThe most powerful manufacturers,we have thebest quality.Wechat:13255996580Whatsapp：+8618820784535
"bio": " เข้าช้อปทุกวันจ้า ซื้อกับวี้ได้ของแท้แน่นอนค่า แบรนด์อื่นสอบถามได้ค่า ดรีวิว@reviewkayasisshopp LINE ID : @kux1427k (มี @ ด้วยจ้า)
```

How to get the data `WhatsApp/Viber Тел: +79858662461` and Email_id `spikydudewonderland@gmail.com`   from it using Regexp or any string manipulation method known.

I want to get only the contact nos like watzapp, line, Wechat, Viber ect and Email_id's from it.

My API is in a loop and calls each time the loop executes which brings the above json response. After that I store the data in excel.

Some responses are totaly in English and some are in other languages. This is causing trouble to extract data.
How to do it? Please help

Comment: Since I am a newbie in regex, I was trying various string manipulations. But those are working for data which is only in english. Sometimes the data is in different language. There I am getting caught up. I was hoping for some help using Regex or a string manipulations which works perfect

Comment: Please post more examples of data you're working with. It's hard to make a regex from just one single sample.

Comment: @Rawing Sure! I have edited my question. Have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to do an acceptable job:

```
(?i)([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*([()+\d -]+\d)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?@?(\w+)|((?:\+\d+[ -]?)?(?:\(\d+\)[ -]?)?\d[\d -]{5,}\d)
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/xQ0fM2/10)

This captures emails in capture group 1, Whatsapp/Viber/Wechat numbers in group 2, and line IDs in group 3.

Usage example:

```
import re

text= '5-yr online store  Real pictures Mirror Quality 1:1 Whatsapp/Viber +861776345378 spikydudewonderland@gmail.com ✈️✈️Worldwide Shipping'
pattern= r'(?i)([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*(\+?\d+)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)'

for mobj in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    if mobj.group(1):
        print 'email:', mobj.group(1)
    elif mobj.group(2):
        t= mobj.group().lower()
        if 'whatsapp' in t:
            print 'whatsapp:', mobj.group(2)
        if 'viber' in t:
            print 'viber:', mobj.group(2)
        if 'wechat' in t:
            print 'wechat:', mobj.group(2)
    elif mobj.group(3):
        print 'line:', mobj.group(3)
```

---

regex explanation:

```
(?i)   case insensitive
([\w.]+@[\w.]+)  something that looks like an email
|      or
(?:    a list of...
   (?:\b|[,/]\s*)
   (?:whatsapp|viber|wechat)  ...whatsapp/viber/wechat
)+\b\s*
[:：]?\s*   possibly followed by a colon
(\+?\d+)   and of course the number
|      or
\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)   something that looks like a line id
```

Comment: Wow! Now this is some hard work done! Thank you so much for your amazing reply @Rawing I will try my code taking help from your answer.

Comment: Buddy, The regex which you have shown here with regex tester site(regex101.com) contains a Modifier "g". How to specify it in the code?

Comment: @rohitnair You don't need to. The `g` modifier on regex101 is the equivalent of using `re.finditer` in python. Without `g` regex101 would only find the first match.

Comment: Well you have helped me enough that I should really not ask more from you but I presently I am stuck so badly in this. I want this regex to even work to find telephone or mobile numbers like `0532 397 49 40` , `1-877-958-5211` or `(38)99937-7007`. I tried to add `^\+(?:[0-9]●?){6,14}[0-9]$` at the end of the regex but its not able to find. Please help a last time!

Comment: @rohitnair That pattern doesn't work because of the `^` and `$` anchors and also because it requires the phone number to start with `+`. Try this one: `(?i)([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*([()+\d -]+)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)|((?:\+\d+)?[ -]?(?:\(\d+\)[ -]?)?[\d -]{6,}\d)` (phone numbers are in capture group 4).

Comment: Hats off man! really...How did you study regex so well! Thank you so much.

Comment: How come this regex Expression is not finding the Line ID for this case `"Menyediakan Kacamata Termurah dengan Kualitas Super\nfrom: Surabaya\nTanya / order : \npin bb : 59f72347\nWA/SMS/Call : 082231506095\nLine : qurotinayunina ` ?  For the cases like `Brandname Hiend สั่งเมื่อพร้อมโอนCFห้ามCCship world wide LINE:@candy_hiend(มี@) candy_hiend@hotmail.com ` , It is finding correctly. I can't find the required change.

Comment: @rohitnair That was my mistake, I'm not familiar with LINE so I assumed the IDs needed to start with a `@` character. I've updated the regex in my answer. Also fixed a small issue with telephone numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I cant find the update which you did though!

Comment: Is it in the demo? or the regex string in your answer at the top of your answer. I tried both of them. Its still not finding the Line ID in the case I mentioned

Comment: @rohitnair I've updated both the pattern at the top of my answer as well as the demo. I've even added the new text sample to the demo, and it does find the Line ID there. If the `\n` in that text are really line breaks and not literal, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Python modules for extracting the phone numbers and emails.

```
      >>> import phonenumbers
      >>> x = phonenumbers.parse("+442083661177", None)
      >>> print x
      Country Code: 44 National Number: 2083661177 Leading Zero: False
```

You can install the module from here. https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers

For email extraction, you can use the following module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/email_extractor

If you get away with special characters, you can use regular expressions

```
   >>> s.lower()
  '"bio": "recruitment agents the most powerful manufacturers,we have thebest quality. wechat:13255996580 whatsapp:+8618820784535'

    >> re.findall(r'whatsapp|viber|wechat\s*.*\d+', s.lower())

    ['wechat:13255996580 whatsapp:+8618820784535']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Well the method which you suggested can get only the numbers right. But as you can see in my JSON string, I want to store the data as `Whatsapp:24987234` If I keep storing only numbers, I will not know whether it is a Whatzapp, Viber, Line or any other application number.  Can you suggest any alternative for that?

Comment: the only option is to use regular expression then. You might want to post more examples for us to look out for.

Comment: Apart from the 1st one, I have posted 3 more in various languages. Will you be requiring more?

Comment: I've added a sample. You may want to look at https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions#basic-examples  for more example

Comment: Thank You for the link @nEO